# What mechanism does 'sqlldr' use to connect to the DB

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-loader

What happens in the background of a 'sqlldr' execution? How does it connect to the database? Is it using ODBC?

Comment: It uses an Oracle client.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What does oracle client do? How does it connect to the database?

Comment: I am curious as to the nature of this question.  Why does this matter to you?  But, while having no sound evidence, I expect SQLLDR connects to the Oracle database via the same ODBC drivers that get installed by the Oracle database client utility package.

Answer (score 0):

sqlldr is Oracle’s data loader utility. In general, the SQL*Loader client utility loads data into a
database at the same release level or higher.

For learning purpose change/remove the PATH environmental variable and then run the sql loader.

Answer (score 0):

Like sqlplus, expdp, impdp the sqlldr utility is an OCI (Oracle Call Interface) application that uses Oracle Net (formerly called "SQL*Net" or "Net8") to connect and communicate with the database. No odbc nor jdbc.